# conflict data type quint16_be from QtEndian with stdint.h

Tags: c++, windows, qt5

I want to use qint16_be, quint16_be, quint32_be etc. as a data type for big endian
what I am trying is something like this

```
#include <QtEndian>
typedef quint16_be uint16_t;
```

And I am getting error

```
C:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/include/QtCore/qendian.h:429:28: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef QBEInteger<short int> qint16_be'
 typedef QBEInteger<qint16> qint16_be;
 C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdint.h:38:25: note: previous declaration as 'typedef short unsigned int qint16_be'
 typedef unsigned short  qint16_be;
```

I have not included stdint.h  in my project.
Any idea how would I resolve it

Comment: Defining `typedef quint16_be uint16_t;` might conflict with [uint16_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) (defined in `stdint.h` and adopted in `cstdint`). That's IMHO a really bad idea and probably the reason for your error. Btw. you're running your code on a big-endian architecture? Do you ever intend it to compile it everywhere else?

Comment: _typedef unsigned short  qint16_be;_ Looks weird somehow. Shouldn't it be _quint16_be_? Typo?

Comment: _I have not included stdint.h in my project._ You not but what about Qt?

Comment: @Scheff Actually my system is little endian. I want to send messages from my system to client via tcp/ip. That system accepts data in big endian.So when I looked at Qt library I found QtEndian store data in bigendian  on all platform so I am tempted to use it and replace all uint16_t , uint32_t with quint16_be , quint32_be etc.

Comment: @Scheff, Yes I know Qt includes stdint.h  and there is typedef of quint16_be. I am wondering if anyhow I can avoid including stdint.h in my project or if you have some other alternatives

Comment: To do this, [qToBigEndian](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html#qToBigEndian-1) and [qFromBigEndian](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html#qFromBigEndian-1) seem the right choice to me.

Comment: The `typedef` is IMHO worth only to give it the right size. Nevertheless, it seems a bit odd to me. I would have used a template class with overloaded assignment which grants that native endian is swapped in case.

Comment: My message is of type struct which I convert into char* to send it to client. Could you give an example of how to use qToBigEndian as this function accepts quint16  etc. my example is clientSocket->write( reinterpret_cast< const char* >( &UpdateBody1 ), sizeof( UpdateBody1 ) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go: an MCVE for [**qToBigEndian()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html#qToBigEndian-1):

```
#include <QtCore>

int main()
{
  const uint16_t sample = 0x0201;
  QByteArray data((const char*)&sample, sizeof sample);
  qDebug() << data;
  const uint16_t sampleBE = qToBigEndian(sample);
  QByteArray dataBE((const char*)&sampleBE, sizeof sampleBE);
  qDebug() << dataBE;
}
```

Output:

```
"\x01\x02"
"\x02\x01"
```

I ran this sample in VS2019 on my Intel laptop which has little-endian architecture.
Respectively, the byte order was changed due to the call of `qToBigEndian()`.

The conversion to `QByteArray` was a quick hack.
Nevertheless, conversion of `const uint16_t*` to `const char*` is allowed (with the intention to get access to the byte representation of something).

[memcpy()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) is another permitted way to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks Scheff, I got an idea. But the main problem is still tehre. If I include <QtEndian>  compiler complains about conflicting declaration.  this is because in stdint.h  we have  typedef unsigned short  qint16_be; while in qtendian.h we have typedef QBEInteger<qint16> qint16_be; where quint16 is of typedef short qint16

Comment: _in stdint.h we have typedef unsigned short qint16_be_ I doubt. (If it would be there, it's not the standard `stdint.h` or it's broken.)

Comment: Thanks Scheff. It is there I would dig more into it. Thanks for the input